# discarding err and output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, io-redirection

I am trying to write a password cracker for cracking password locked pdf.
I have 4 for loops too iterate through all the possible 4 char passwords.
I have a command that gives out error messages if the password is wrong. presently i redirect the error and output to a temporary file and delete the file after every check. This consumes a lot of time and is making the script slower.
If anyone could suggest me a better idea or redirection that would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance
Harsha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to /dev/null thus discarding the standard output and standard error completely.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I just found it!